# Qt 'slots' does not name a type

Tags: c++, qt

Есть класс:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QUdpSocket>

class MyUDP : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyUDP(QObject *parent = 0);
public slots:
    void read();

private:
    QUdpSocket *socket;

};
```

Но компилятор выдаёт ошибку:

> ошибка: 'slots' does not name a type

В чём может быть причина?

Comment: В приведённом код всё чисто. Возможно, где-то в другом месте `slots` переопределён как переменная или что-то ещё.

Comment: Нет, slots не переопределён.

Comment: @Logotipo опишите, пожалуйста, последовательность шагов, которая воспроизводит указанную ошибку. [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заменил

```
public slots:
```

на

```
public Q_SLOTS:
```

Возможно это связано с тем, что я использую boost. Хотя никакие файлы boost не были включены в файлы с этим классом.

Comment: В проекте не указана директива `CONFIG += no_keywords`? http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#using-qt-with-3rd-party-signals-and-slots

Comment: @Arhad, указана

Comment: Вот, она и отменяет объявление макросов `slots` и `signals`.