# Q_OBJECT doesn't name a type

Tags: qt

Почему в моём случае я вижу сообщение об ошибке
Q_OBJECT doesn't name a type

```
namespace ised
{

class ised_win : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    
public:
    enum PersonType
    {
        operator_=0,
        technician=1,
        engineer=2
    };

    // ctro & dtor

    ised_win(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ised_win();
    void onBtnPressed();
public slots:
    void accept();//scp
    //void reject


private:
    QWidget m_w;
    QLineEdit* m_edit;
    QString m_session;
};
} // namespace ised
```

Это [Qt 'slots' does not name a type](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540873/qt-slots-does-not-name-a-type)
не помогло, а точнее ключевое слово Q_SLOTS.
Я, конечно, подключил QMainWindow:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте

```
#include <QObject>
```

Вы скорее всего не включили его